# In App Billing without using bindService

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I want to add in app billing to my app. Is there any way without explicitly calling the boolean bindService(Intent intent,ServiceConnection conn,int i)?

Comment: whats wrong with `bindService` ?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with it. Lets just say I have a situation that prevents me from explicitly calling it anywhere in my app code.